# Calculating CSS transform matrix for SVG animation of rotation during translation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

The square should be animated to rotate while moving along a straight line from the red square to the blue square. I can't get this to work as you can see from the moving square never matching the fixed blue square.

That problem appears repeatedly, therefore I need a reusable solution. That is: don't just give specific numbers for the matrix but also the calculation by which you arrived at those values.

So I need a `matrix()` transform in terms of the following variables:

- `x1,y1` is the initial point of the straight movement path (in the example below `75,75`);
- `x2,y2` is the final point of the straight movement path (in the example below `175,75`);
- `cx,cy` is the center of rotation (in the example below `75,75`);
- `a` as angle by which to rotate (in the example below `45deg` - I would prefer giving the value in radians but CSS doesn't seem to accept that);

such that the object rotates around `cx,cy` by angle `a` while the point `x1,y1` moves to `x2,y2` along a straight line (note that while `x1,y1` and `cx,cy` coincide in the example below this is not always the case, but the example was supposed to be simple).

Note that I do know how the matrices work, including how to compose transformations. The problem is that I do not know which particular transformations I need for this specific problem.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="250px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 250 150">
 <style>
 *{stroke:black;stroke-width:1px;}

 @keyframes ani {
  0% {fill:#f00;transform:translate(0, 0 );}
  /* illustrating that movement works without rotation. */
  25% {fill:#00f;transform: translate( 100px, 0 );}
  50% {fill:#f00;transform:translate(0, 0 );}
  /* with rotation it ends up anywhere but where it is supposed to go. */
  75% {fill:#00f;transform: translate( 100px, 0 ) translate( 175px, 75px) rotate( 45deg ) translate( -175px, -75px );}
  100% {fill:#f00;transform:translate(0, 0 );}
 }
 #p {animation: ani 4000ms ease-in-out 10ms infinite normal forwards;}
 </style>

 <defs>
  <path id="def" d="m0,0 l50,0 l0,50 l-50,0 l0,-50" />
 </defs>

 <use xlink:href="#def" x="50" y="50" style="fill:#faa;" />
 <use xlink:href="#def" x="150" y="50" style="fill:#aaf;" transform="rotate( 45 175 75 )" />
 
 <use id="p" xlink:href="#def" x="50" y="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Questions that ask for library recommendations are actually off topic, but ok, here you go: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: I am not asking for a library recommendation, I am asking to show me the path of calculation instead of only the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix I believe you want is basically this (thank you to [this page](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/) for helping me figure it out):

```
transform: matrix(cos(angle),sin(angle),-sin(angle),cos(angle),translateDiffX,translateDiffY);
```

I don't think you can set trigonometry values in CSS (except perhaps with a pre-processor), so I made **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f0wv0yz/3/)** where the CSS is overwritten via JavaScript (though in a sort of heavy-handed way), and changed up the angles and translation values to test to make sure it worked for other cases.

Note that without the `transform-origin` at the 0% and 100%, the animation has a sort of arc effect (though perhaps that's desirable/unimportant).